# Retrofit Call has same name different data type

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit2

API call

```
@GET("users/{user_id}/grid")
    Call<ArrayList<Grid>> getGrid(@Path("user_id") Integer id, @Header("Authorization") String authHeader);

Grid.class
public class Grid {

        @SerializedName("category")
        @Expose
        private String category;

        @SerializedName("type")
        @Expose
        private String type;

        @SerializedName("title")
        @Expose
        private String title;

        @SerializedName("equation_list")
        @Expose
        private List<Integer> equationList = null;  // This is the issue
}
```

API response equation_list field contains Integer array or string. 
ex:

```
"equation_list": "7", or 
"equation_list": [7],
```

But i got exception

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1586 path
>   $[5].equation_list

How do i fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create a type to handle both data types **String** and **ArrayList**. Then you can implement a custom `JsonAdapter` for GSON to handle the custom deserialization for this type.

Let's create `EquationList` derived from `java.util.ArrayList`

```java
/**
 * Custom type to handle both String and ArrayList<Integer> types
 *
 * @author Yavuz Tas
 *
 */
public class EquationList extends ArrayList<Integer> {

}
```

After we implement `JsonAdapter` for `EquationList` type

```java
/**
 * Custom JsonAdapter for GSON to handle {@link EquationList} converstion
 * 
 * @author Yavuz Tas
 *
 */
public class EquationListJsonAdapter extends TypeAdapter<EquationList> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, EquationList user) throws IOException {

        // Since we do not serialize EquationList by gson we can omit this part.
        // If you need you can check
        // com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter class
        // read method for a basic object serialize implementation

    }

    @Override
    public EquationList read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

        EquationList deserializedObject = new EquationList();

        // type of next token
        JsonToken peek = in.peek();

        // if the json field is string
        if (JsonToken.STRING.equals(peek)) {
            String stringValue = in.nextString();
            // convert string to integer and add to list as a value
            deserializedObject.add(Integer.valueOf(stringValue));
        }

        // if it is array then implement normal array deserialization
        if (JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY.equals(peek)) {
            in.beginArray();

            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String element = in.nextString();
                deserializedObject.add(Integer.valueOf(element));
            }

            in.endArray();
        }

        return deserializedObject;
    }
}
```

And last we register our adapter to our `equationList` field in `Grid`

```java
public class Grid {

    @SerializedName("category")
    @Expose
    private String category;

    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    @JsonAdapter(value = EquationListJsonAdapter.class)
    @SerializedName("equation_list")
    @Expose
    private EquationList equationList;

}
```

This should handle your responses correctly like below

```
"equation_list": "7", or "equation_list": [7]
```

Please note that any `String` response automatically converted to `Integer` and added to `EquationList` as an list element. You can alter this behaivor by changing the implementation in `read` method of `EquationListJsonAdapter`.

I hope this helps. Cheers!